# Inequality with little-o notation

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

I'm having trouble justifying the following:
For large $n$,
\begin{align*}
-\log f(n) & < \log n + o(\log n)\\
\implies f(n) &> n^{-1} \log^3(n) \log(10)
\end{align*}

I think basically for large $n$ they claim $e^{-o(\log n)} > \log^3(n) \log(10)$?

**Edit**: the first inequality should have been strict, corrected

Answer (score 1):

No wonder you have trouble justifying it, because the implication is false. The function $f(n)= n^{-1}$ is a counterexample: it satisfies the first asymptotic relation, but not the second.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. What if the first inequality were instead $-\log f(n) \le c\log n + o(\log n)$ for some fixed $c$ satisfying $0\le c<1$? Then we have $f(n) \ge n^{-c} e^{-o(\log n)}$, so we need to show $e^{-o(\log n)} n^{1-c} > \log^3(n) \log(10)$ for large $n$, which does seem to hold? I'm a little uncomfortable with dealing with the $o(\log n)$ term here.